# move index from 0 to 1 when saving core data attributes

Tags: swift, core-data, indexing, fetch, binary-data

My swift code below saves 2 images to binary core data. When the user enters 1 or 0 in the textfield the imageview fetchs the data and displays. I want to move the index to start at 1 instead of starting at 0. When the user enters 0 into the text field nothing in the imageview should show up. In my core data model pic is the binary data.

```
 import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet var labelName : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var enterT : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pic : UIImageView!
lazy var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enterT.delegate = self

    pic.backgroundColor = .cyan
    populateData()
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), let index = Int(text) else { //here....
        // display an alert about invalid text
        return true
    }
    loadImage(at: index )
    return true
}

func loadImage(at index : Int) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
    do {
        if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            pic.image = UIImage(data: user.image!)
        } else {
           pic.image = nil
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
    }
}

@IBAction func add(){
    // fetch()
}

func populateData()
{
    let item = Users(context: context)
    let vex = UIImage(named: "on.jpg")!.pngData()
    item.image = vex
    item.idx = 0

    let item2 = Users(context: context)
    let vex2 = UIImage(named: "house.jpg")!.pngData()
    item2.image = vex2
    item2.idx = 1

    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed", error)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you just check if `index == 0` then return `nil`

Comment: Please, I told you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020522/binary-data-not-fetching-in-uiimageview-when-called) how to do that. Delete the app in the simulator or the device, in the code change `item.idx = 0` to `item.idx = 1` and `item.idx = 1` to `item.idx = 2`. Then run the app once, quit it immediately and delete or comment out  `populateData()` in `viewDidLoad`. For the last time, if you don't do that the two items are inserted again and again on each launch. Please try to understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to call `index - 1`

When the user enters 0 into the text field nothing in the `imageview` will show up because index - 1 becomes -1 and `NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))` return nil

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), let index = Int(text) else { //here....
        // display an alert about invalid text
        return true
    }
    loadImage(at: index - 1 )
    return true
}
```

hope it will help you =) happy coding

**OR** what you can do is to save index in `coredata` accordingly after deleting the app

```
func populateData()
{
    let item = Users(context: context)
    let vex = UIImage(named: "on.jpg")!.pngData()
    item.image = vex
    item.idx = 1

    let item2 = Users(context: context)
    let vex2 = UIImage(named: "house.jpg")!.pngData()
    item2.image = vex2
    item2.idx = 2

    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed", error)
    }
}
```